# creating a Grails application in IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.x fails to prompt for "create-app"

Tags: grails, osx-snow-leopard, intellij-idea

When I create a Grails application in IntelliJ 9 on Snow Leopard I am not prompted to create an application.  IntelliJ finished the wizard and creates an empty project that is not a Grails application.  I have tried two different Apple computers (MacBook Pro and Mac Pro) it does not work on either.  The same steps on a Linux system results in a prompt to "create-app" and a Grails application.

I have already tried the steps in [Intellij IDEA setup on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470882/intellij-idea-setup-on-os-x)

Is there a specific place that Grails needs to be installed?  Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Thanks

Answer: Make sure that the grails directory is writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the grails directory is writable.

I moved my grails install from /opt/grails-1.2.1 to /Users/dave/grails-1.2.1 and I can now create or import grails applications.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this on Snow Leopard running Intellij 94.633 (EAP) + grails 1.2.1 and the create new project wizard has worked just fine.

Started with 'create new project', selected a grails module, was then prompted to 'create-app' or 'create-plugin' and was presented with a completed project.

Might be an idea to try the same EAP build if no joy you will have to file a bug with jetbrains. They are pretty good at responding to issues, you should get some sort of feed back pretty soon.

This is actually the first time I've actually done that in intellji, previously I've always just used the grails command line and then just imported the application to Intellij.

Comment: What is the path to your grails install?  I have it installed at /opt/grails-1.2.1

It should not make a difference, but it might

Comment: echo $GRAILS_HOME -> /Users/gareth/local/grails which is a sym link to /Users/gareth/local/grails-1.2.1, Although Idea has the SDK pointing to directly to the versioned directory