# What is path of JDK on Mac ?

Tags: macos, java

Im using Mac only at work and I need to set JAVA_HOME to proper path of JDK. I downloaded JDK, installed it and now I can't find it anywhere. I was looking at the internet for the solution, but there is no folder Libraries/Java.

Comment: found it here: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: You should use /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines so IDEA picks up sources and javadoc properly. At the time of this writing, the correct path was /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470882/intellij-idea-setup-on-os-x

Comment: On Mac Sierra I've /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines which has jdk and System Preferences > Java what's different between these 2 ?

Comment: This question has a really good 487-vote answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18144853/1099571, which is has a very interesting detail not found in any of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing . I think it's misleading to have a duplicate marker which says "This question already has an answer" over there; maybe that question should point here. Or, someone should make an answer with the best from both questions.

Comment: Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` command on a terminal shell to figure out where is your **Java 1.8** home directory. If you just want to find out the home directory of your most recent version of Java run `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score 760, accepted):

The location has changed from Java 6 (provided by Apple) to Java 7 and onwards (provided by Oracle). The best *generic* way to find this out is to run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

This is the natively supported way to find out both the path to the default Java installation as well as all alternative ones present.

If you check out its help text (`java_home -h`), you'll see that you can use this command to reliably start a Java program on OS X (`java_home --exec ...`), with the ability to explicitly specify the desired Java version and architecture, or even request the user to install it if missing.

A more pedestrian approach, but one which will help you trace specifically which Java installation the command `java` resolves into, goes like this:

1. run

   ```
   which java
   ```
2. if that gives you something like `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symbolic link to the real location, run

   ```
   ls -l `which java`
   ```

   On my system, this outputs

   ```
   /usr/bin/java -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   ```

   and therefrom you can read the Java home directory;
3. if `usr/bin/java` points to another symbolic link, recursively apply the same approach with

   ```
   ls -l <whatever the /usr/bin/java symlink points to>
   ```

---

An important variation is the setup you get if you start by installing Apple's Java and later install Oracle's. In that case Step 2 above will give you

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/java
```

and that particular `java` binary is a stub which will resolve the actual `java` command to call by consulting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and, if it's not set or doesn't point to a Java home directory, will fall back to calling `java_home`. It is important to have this in mind when debugging your setup.

Comment: thanks! Step 2 is a great tip with the symbolic link !

Comment: found it here: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: And how do I remove Apple's Java?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Using java_home as keyword, I found a good overview here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/01-JavaOverview/JavaOverview.html

Comment: Although good quality, the article is outdated. Apple no longer supports Java and OS X is shipped without it.

Comment: running `/usr/libexec/java_home -version 1.8` helped me in seconds!

Comment: [Update] When setting up the JDK in IntelliJ for El Capitan, one would set it to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/

Comment: BTW, the [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be/) program might help when it comes to manage many Java versions.

Comment: This is simply great. Helped me to nail down the exact path to installation.

Comment: running `which java` did it for me

Answer (score 39):

Which Mac version are you using? try these paths

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/ OR
 /usr/libexec/java_home
```

This link might help - [How To Set $JAVA_HOME Environment Variable On Mac OS X](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 27):

Have a look and see if the the JDK is at:

Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
Or
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Check this earlier SO post:
[JDK on OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614380/jdk-on-osx-10-7-lion)

Comment: That's what I needed to add a JDK 1.8 to my Eclipse install. Thank you!

Comment: That's the right path for me with JDK 1.8 and Mac OS X Yosemite. Though full path that I needed for set for JAVA_HOME was /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 8):

On my Mac:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/
```

btw, did you tried `which java`?

Answer (score 6):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/`

Also see [Java 7 path on mountain lion](http://kunaldabir.blogspot.in/2013/01/java-7-and-groovy-on-mac-os-x-mountain.html)

Comment: yes, it shows /usr/bin/java and it seems to not be a symbolic link