# How do I add Java 1.8 to IntelliJ (OSX)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to create a new JavaFX project. I have 1.8 installed which I believe includes the javafx packages. Running `javac -version` in the terminal shows `javac 1.8.0_121`. I installed from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

When I go to `File -> Project Structure -> Project` the selected version is `1.6`. There is no `1.8` version in the list. If I select add new, and navigate to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` I see:

```
1.4
1.4.2
1.5
1.5.0
1.6
1.6.0
```

There is no `1.8` version.

How can I update IntelliJ to user version `1.8`?

Comment: I'm no Mac expert but `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` does not sound like the path of the JDK.

Comment: After a bit of googling, `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` sounds like the place to look.

Comment: @Michael there is no `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` directory. I'm on El Capitan if that helps. How can I find out where it's stored?

Comment: @Michael http://i.imgur.com/GPn1net.png ... Doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe you must configure your IDE to use that location? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk#18987229

Answer (score 6):

The location for the SDK can be found by running: `echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Which reveals:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain how the command `echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)` works?

Edit: found it http://stackoverflow.com/a/18144853/1092133

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Java with brew.
/Users/{username}/.sdkman/candidates/java/current

To show .sdkman in finder

> Press Cmd+Shift+. to show hidden files in the file chooser dialog.
>   https://guides.codepath.com/android/setting-up-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to this party, today I had the same problem.
The right answer I think is use [`jenv`](https://www.jenv.be/)

```
brew install jenv openjdk@8
jenv add /usr/local/opt/openjdk@8
```

And then add into Intellij IDEA as new SDK the following path:

```
~/.jenv/versions/1.8/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/
```